# AWS CodePipeline complaining about "AppSec" artefact, what is it?

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-codepipeline

I have an AWS CodePipeline configured for ECS. I have taskdef.json and appspec.yaml in my project's root directory.

I get a strange error on the Deploy stage and it says:

```
Exception while trying to read the AppSec artifact file from: BuildArtifact.
```

what is this `AppSec` here, it complained about `appspec.yaml` that would make sense but any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar issue, except we had an exception when reading from the SourceArtifact. We reviewed the artifacts for the failed deploy and noticed it was hitting the 3MB limit allowed for Source Artifacts.

[Troubleshooting here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/troubleshooting.html)

I don't see anything about Build Artifact size limits, however I recommend you check out what the actual Build Artifact you are producing looks like. It should be a couple of JSON files e.g. taskDef.json minimally.

I would ensure your artifacts are valid JSON and properly being built. You can do this by looking at the Execution History finding the proper artifacts for your deployment:

[image: Artifacts]

Comment: I can't remember what exactly I did to fix it but I think it was an issue with the CodeDeploy configuration.